# What is the best way to change the order of array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the easiest way to re-order an array of objects as below.

I want to re-order it based on group value (custom order)

```
[ { groupValue: 'Corp',
    doclist: { numFound: 259, start: 0, maxScore: 1.1320078, docs: [Object] } },
  { groupValue: 'Phone',
    doclist: { numFound: 7975, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2560269, docs: [Object] } },
  { groupValue: 'Shop',
    doclist: { numFound: 9, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2556685, docs: [Object] } } ]
```

If I pass in argument with the group value, that particular object corresponding to the group value should come up on the top

Something like

```
function ("Shop",originalArray){
 return newArray;
}
```

Should return:

```
    [ { groupValue: 'Shop',
        doclist: { numFound: 9, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2556685, docs: [Object] } },
{ groupValue: 'Corp',
        doclist: { numFound: 259, start: 0, maxScore: 1.1320078, docs: [Object] } },
      { groupValue: 'Phone',
        doclist: { numFound: 7975, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2560269, docs: [Object] } }]
```

Comment: In this case you only want to move the object to the top level, at index 0?

Comment: Is the order of the rest of the elements important?

Comment: Yes, I just need to move the specific object with the group value to the top and leave the rest as is.

Answer (score 9):

This should work, gives a new array and should go through the original just once.

```js
var data = [{
  groupValue: 'Corp',
  doclist: {
    numFound: 259,
    start: 0,
    maxScore: 1.1320078,
    docs: [Object]
  }
}, {
  groupValue: 'Phone',
  doclist: {
    numFound: 7975,
    start: 0,
    maxScore: 1.2560269,
    docs: [Object]
  }
}, {
  groupValue: 'Shop',
  doclist: {
    numFound: 9,
    start: 0,
    maxScore: 1.2556685,
    docs: [Object]
  }
}];

function goFirst(d, daFirst) {
  var r = [];

  d.forEach((e) => {
    if (e['groupValue'] === daFirst)
      r.unshift(e);
    else
      r.push(e);
  })

  return r;
}

console.log(goFirst(data, 'Shop'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a custom function to `Array.prototype.sort`:

```
function sortBy(arr, val, prop) {
    return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        if (b[prop] == val) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
 }

console.log(sortBy(arr, "Shop", "groupValue"))
```

As the order for the rest of the elements is important for you (should stay the same), go with this:

```
function sortBy(arr, val, prop) {
  var top = [];
  var rest = [];
    /* see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of 
    for "for of" loops, you might want to use a forEach() loop as "for of" isn't supported in many browsers as of now
    */
  for (var el of arr) {  
    if (el[prop] == val) {
        top.push(el)
    } else {
        rest.push(el);
    }
  }
  return top.concat(rest);
}

 console.log(sortBy(arr, "Shop", "groupValue"))
```

Comment: This might have the side-effect of rearranging all other elements in the array. MDN says: "The sort is not necessarily stable".

Comment: In this case the input array is modified, as I understand OP asked for a `newArray` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to move the elements in the array:

```js
var arr = [ { groupValue: 'Corp',
    doclist: { numFound: 259, start: 0, maxScore: 1.1320078 } },
  { groupValue: 'Phone',
    doclist: { numFound: 7975, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2560269 } },
  { groupValue: 'Shop',
    doclist: { numFound: 9, start: 0, maxScore: 1.2556685 } } ];

function move(option,originalArray){
  var newArray = originalArray.slice();      
  newArray.splice(0,0,newArray.filter(item => item.groupValue == option)[0]);
  return newArray;
}

console.log(move("Shop",arr));
```

`splice` first 0 indicate where to put the new value. The second 0 indicate what to do with the other elements (0 indicate move them), the third argument is the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "sort" function to place the item first according to the value

```js
var originalArray = [{
        groupValue: 'Corp',
        doclist: {
            numFound: 259,
            start: 0,
            maxScore: 1.1320078,
            docs: [Object]
        }
    },
    {
        groupValue: 'Phone',
        doclist: {
            numFound: 7975,
            start: 0,
            maxScore: 1.2560269,
            docs: [Object]
        }
    },
    {
        groupValue: 'Shop',
        doclist: {
            numFound: 9,
            start: 0,
            maxScore: 1.2556685,
            docs: [Object]
        }
    }
]

var reorder = function (attr, originalArray){
    var newArray = originalArray.slice() // clone array
    newArray.sort(function(a){return a.groupValue !== attr?1:-1}) // put in first
    return newArray;
}

// groupValue === Shop in first
console.log(reorder("Shop", originalArray))
```